# How to find folder below given section of a path?

Tags: c#, .net, directory-traversal

Given a path and a certain section, how can I find the name of the folder immediately below that section?

This is hard to explain, let me give some examples. Suppose I am looking for the name of the folder below 'Dev/Branches'. Below are example inputs, with the expected results in bold

- C:\Code\Dev\Branches\ **Latest** \bin\abc.dll
- C:\Dev\Branches\ **5.1**
- D:\My Documents\Branches\ **7.0** \Source\Tests\test.cs

I am using C#

Edit: I suppose I could use the regex `/Dev/Branches/(.*?)/` capturing the first group, but is there a neater solution without regex? That regex would fail on the second case, anyway.

Comment: You're going to have to make one of two assumptions. That there is only one folder directly below `Branches` or that you're going to grab the first one alphabetically. Is that really what you're looking for?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I believe OP means next section in the given path

Comment: You don't want to use string find functions to locate the string between two slashes?

Comment: Right, as @defaultlocale says. I don't care what's actually on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this

```
public static string GetBranchName(string path, string prefix)
{
    string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

    // Walk up the path until it ends with Dev\Branches
    while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(folder) && folder.Contains(prefix))
    {
        string parent = Path.GetDirectoryName(folder);
        if (parent != null && parent.EndsWith(prefix))
            return Path.GetFileName(folder);

        folder = parent;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// starting path
string path = @"C:\Code\Dev\Branches\Latest\bin\abc.dll";

// search path
string search = @"Dev\Branches";

// find the index of the search criteria
int idx = path.IndexOf(search);

// determine whether to exit or not
if (idx == -1 || idx + search.Length >= path.Length) return;

// get the substring AFTER the search criteria, split it and take the first item
string found = path.Substring(idx + search.Length).Split("\\".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).First();

Console.WriteLine(found);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code that will do exactly what you expect:

```
public static string GetSubdirectoryFromPath(string path, string parentDirectory, bool ignoreCase = true)
{
    // 1. Standarize the path separators.
    string safePath = path.Replace("/", @"\");
    string safeParentDirectory = parentDirectory.Replace("/", @"\").TrimEnd('\\');

    // 2. Prepare parentDirectory to use in Regex.
    string directory = Regex.Escape(safeParentDirectory);

    // 3. Find the immediate subdirectory to parentDirectory.
    Regex match = new Regex(@"(?:|.+)" + directory + @"\\([^\\]+)(?:|.+)", ignoreCase ? RegexOptions.IgnoreCase : RegexOptions.None);

    // 4. Return the match. If not found, it returns null.
    string subDirectory = match.Match(safePath).Groups[1].ToString();
    return subDirectory == "" ? null : subDirectory;
}
```

A test code:

```
void Test()
{
    string path1 = @"C:\Code\Dev\Branches\Latest\bin\abc.dll";
    string path2 = @"C:\Dev\Branches\5.1";
    string path3 = @"D:\My Documents\Branches\7.0\Source\test.cs";

    Console.WriteLine("Matches:");
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path1, "dev/branches/") ?? "Not found");
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path1, @"Dev\Branches") ?? "Not found");
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path3, "D:/My Documents/Branches") ?? "Not found");
    // Incorrect parent directory.
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path2, "My Documents") ?? "Not found");
    // Case sensitive checks.
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path3, @"My Documents\Branches", false) ?? "Not found");
    Console.WriteLine(GetSubdirectoryFromPath(path3, @"my Documents\Branches", false) ?? "Not found");

    // Output:
    //
    // Matches:
    // Latest
    // Latest
    // 7.0
    // Not found
    // 7.0
    // Not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Break it down into smaller steps and you can solve this yourself:

1. (Optional, depending on further requirements): Get the directory name (file is irrelevant): [`Path.GetDirectoryName(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)
2. Get its parent directory [`Directory.GetParent(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

This comes down to;

```
 var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(input);
 var parentDirectory = Directory.GetParent(directory);
```

The supplied `C:\Dev\Branches\5.1` -> `5.1` does not conform to your specification, that is the directory name of the input path itself. This will output `Branches`.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Regex("\\?" + PathToMatchEscaped + "\\(\w+)\\?").Match()...
```